# Best approach to give specific tables permissions programmatically to users?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, user-permissions

We have an existing working system and I am asked to change the current logic of giving "permissions" to the users. The current logic is not very appropriate and in terms of performance, it is too slow.

### **Current Structure**

Currently, we have 25 tables and much more to come and we have 110 system users. Some are admin and some are simple users with specific permissions. We are using M-V-C Entity Framework Code First Approach in our system.

For every table, we have 5 Checkboxes like this first check box for giving permission to access a page, second to create data, third to read data, fourth to update data and fifth to delete data.

### **Problem**

Now all these permissions are in one User Table so there are total 125 columns in User table. 25 tables x 5 Checkboxes = 125 columns.

So, when we are registering user we can select permissions e.g.  `user1` only can read country records from country table, and only can add or edit cities from cities table and only can delete religions from religions table.

Also, is system there are 125 different roles. e.g. `CountryCreate`, `CountryDelete`, `CityCreate`, `CityDelete` and so on.

During user registration, system associates different roles to user depending upon the checked value. SO let's say if admin wants to give 70 permissions to user then 70 roles will be associated with that particular user and since there are many users so thousands of `UserRoles`. Roles are created to check in views if user is in particular role then show particular functionality e.g. country create, otherwise don't show it.

The application stop working most of the times. Because there are so many roles and check boxes associated with every user.

I am new to the project, and the first job is to change the permissions logic. What is the best way to achieve it?

### Current Code

```
if (model.countryRead == true)
{
  var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
                    userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "countryRead");
}
```

So, like this we have 125 `if statements` and it is only for Register. In edit, we also have `else statements` to remove from role if checkbox is false. Plus, we have 125 properties in the user model.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the way you're handling permissions. In fact, that's sort of the way you're *supposed* to handle permissions. If your app is crashing or something, that's a separate unrelated issue. Either the code is bad or inefficient, the server(s) don't have enough resources, your database needs to be tuned, etc. You mold your environment to your architecture, not the other way around.

Comment: So you mean having table with 125 columns and roles is not a problem?

Comment: Define "problem". It's not like there's some kind of magical number of *things* you can have before you have to throw your approach away and start over. You're building an application to satisfy your business. Whatever is required to do that is required. Speaking more theoretically, there's no inherent issue with having something like 125 columns in a SQL table. It's not like SQL Server goes "Nope, I'm only going to support 124. Now you're toast." If there's performance issues or other problems, you can solve those in other ways, by adding more resources, etc.

Comment: I will say, though, that if you're storing the user's membership in each role as a column in some table, that's the wrong approach. Whether or not the checkbox in the form will be checked or not should depend on the user's existing role memberships, not some flag in some table. You're essentially denormalizing your data by storing the actual checkbox value.Build your checkbox list based on a list of all roles and then check the box or not, based on whether the user is actually in that role.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this approach:

You have already had `User` and `Role` Models. you need just another Model with this structure:

```
public enum Actions
{
    Insert,
    Delete,
    Update,
    GetOne,
    GetAll
}

public enum Services
{
    Country,
    Category,
    Product,
    Warehouse
}

public class UserAccess
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Actions Action { get; set; }
    public Services Service { get; set; }
}
```

> with this model, you can define infinite access. the `Users` have `Roles`
>   and every `Role` can have lots of `UserAccess`.

after that, you must check it manually like `125 if statements` or make a better way, I suggest you if you are using Web API:

first, you must inherit from `AuthorizeAttribute` class and customize it with your access Models like `Users`, `Roles` and `UserAccesses` and also you must override `OnAuthorization` method like:

```
public class ServiceAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public ServiceAuthorize(Actions action, params Services[] services)
        {
            this.action = action;
            this.services = services.ToList();
        }
        private Actions action { get; set; }
        private List<Services> services { get; set; }
        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
              // check the user's roles here
              // if the user don't have needed role or access you can reject it with this code
             if (Unauthorized)
             {
                 actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(
                                    HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
                                    new Dictionary<string, string> {
                                                { HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized.ToString(), ((int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized).ToString() }
                                   }
                   );
             } 
        }
    }
```

then, you must use this attribute above `Controllers` or `Actions` like this in your Web API:

```
 public class CountryController : ApiController
    {
        [ServiceAuthorize(new List<Actions>() { Actions.GetAll }, new List<Services>() { Services.Country })]
        public string GetCountries()
        {

        }

        [ServiceAuthorize(new List<Actions>() { Actions.Insert }, new List<Services>() { Services.Country })]
         public string AddCountry(Country country)
         {

         }
    }
```

*I hope it would be helpful.*

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to give advice without knowing much about what your project structure is like (or where the bottleneck actually is), but there are at least 5 things you could possibly do in order to help fix performance issues:

1. Instead of using 5 `boolean` fields for permissions, use a single bitwise `int` field, and translate the value to 5 check boxes on the UI. For example, `1=access;2=create;4=read;8=update;16=delete`, so if the value of the field is 13, the user will have access, read, and update (1+4+8=13).
2. It is unclear why there is a column for each table. It would make more sense to have a row for each table, then you could have a single column for permissions.
3. It sounds like overkill to have both "check boxes" and "roles". If each of your roles is a permission, you could just eliminate the "permissions" table altogether.
4. You could significantly improve performance by caching the permissions (and/or roles) in memory using `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache`.
5. Make sure your roles/permissions are not kept in cookies because that means the *every HTTP request* be it a page, image, CSS file, etc. will send the cookies round trip, which can translate to a lot of extra bytes of network traffic.

### Permission Table

Not sure why the client "wants the table". Maybe they want the data (which already exists as roles) and that is the way you are interpreting it. Your first choice should be to eliminate the data duplication and just use roles (since roles are readily usable by MVC).

If not possible, then this is something along the lines of what you could do

```
UserID | Table (string)           | Permission (int)
---------------------------------------------------
1      | Table1                   | 13
1      | Table2                   | 17
2      | Table5                   | 3
```

Keep in mind it is your application that controls "permission", not the way the data is actually stored. But a maintainable database will only store data in one place, letting the application deal with how to use, display, and update the data.

Comment: Yes, I was also thinking to use int instead of bool. I did not understand the second time, what do you mean by one column for permissions? Yes, I can eliminate permission table but client wants the table.